# my php script unable to parse json file

Tags: php, ajax, json

i m getting this error requested json parsed to failed..i have wriiten the php script for reading the response from server side,but i have not installed php..?is it required for running the script..?is this the reason for getting error of parsing..?
this is my php code.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);

$json = "url";
 var_dump(json_decode($jsonfile));  
 echo json_decode($jsonfile);
?>
```

Comment: Not Installed PHP? OMG!

Comment: Nothing in that code is going to report the error "requested json parsed to failed". Please delete this question. Go back to the last time you asked it. Then edit it to describe the *exact* error message you are getting and where it is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

> i have wriiten the php script for reading the response from server side,but i have not installed php..?i

To run PHP you need to install PHP. Then you can run the PHP script and give us the error details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you have installed php and curl

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'URLtotheserver');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);    
$json = json_decode($json,true);
```

Comment: i m getting json parser error from my client code only..but donk know where i am wrong.?i  used data:{data:form.serializeArray()}still getting the same error.unable to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try **`cURL`**

```
$json = "urltotheserver";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
print_r(json_decode($data,1));
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [status] => Array
        (
            [statusCode] => 555
            [errorMessage] => Email address should not be blank
            [title] => Email address not in request
            [classname] => RegistrationController
        )

)
```